# awk: $2 == /"foo"/ { ... } does not work as expected (matching $2 exactly to foo, quoted)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

With this file example :

```
"line1_value1","foo","line1_value3"
"line2_value1","faa","line2_value3"
"line3_value1","faa","line3_value3"
"line4_value1","foo","line4_value3"
"line3_value1","faa ","line3_value3"
```

I want get all lines with the second column exactly equal to "faa" in the second column. With my example, this match with the lines 2 and 3. I tried that :

```
awk -F, '$2 == /"foo"/ { print $0 }' example_file
```

But this command returns nothing...Where am I wrong?

Comment: chuckling... "*`awk` doesn't work when...*" 99% of the time, it's not `awk`'s fault....

Comment: I agree, but I choosen a sample title, I'm not a great english writter ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do equality test on the `,` separated second field:

```
awk -F, '$2 == "\"faa\""' file.txt
```

Also here, you need to escape the inner `"`s to make it literal inside `"`s.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                      
"line1_value1","foo","line1_value3"
"line2_value1","faa","line2_value3"
"line3_value1","faa","line3_value3"
"line4_value1","foo","line4_value3"
"line3_value1","faa ","line3_value3"

% awk -F, '$2 == "\"faa\""' file.txt
"line2_value1","faa","line2_value3"
"line3_value1","faa","line3_value3"
```

---

**Reason your one failed:**

You have used:

```
awk -F, '$2 == /"foo"/ { print $0 }'
```

- `//` incurs Regex match in `awk`, and returns `0` (no match) or `1` (match)
- `$2 == /"foo"/` is necessarily comparing (for equality) the second field with the integer `0` or `1`, which will always be evaluated to false in this case. Also, `/"foo"/` here is matching the pattern `"foo"` against the whole record
- So, remember that, `/<pattern>/` is shorthand for `$0 ~ /<pattern>/` hence your `$2 == /"foo"/` is a shorthand for `$2 == ($0 ~ /"foo"/)`

Comment: @user2137454 You got the right way to do what you want but do you understand what the code you wrote means and why that didn't do what you wanted? I think that would be a valuable addition to this answer.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't understand why use "\"faa\"" instead of /"faa"/. By definition,the awk command needs use the " delimiter for describe the regex pattern ?